# Cart price rule apply coupon discount for all product not only selected sku magento 2

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

[image]
i have cart price rule ( coupon Code)for 6 products which is working fine but when we add product not under the rule also get the discount
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a second section where you have to specify on which product the rule should be applied :

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items).

It is there that you should set the sku on which your rule apply and I think you could remove everything in the first condition section that you have.

[image]

Comment: HI Sir , thanks , yes it is what  i was looking , You really saved my time ...